# Java generics issue: Class "not within bounds of type-variable" error.

Tags: java, generics, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a project for class that involves generics.

```
public interface Keyable <T> {public String getKey();}

public interface DataElement extends Comparable<Keyable<DataElement>>, Keyable<DataElement>, Serializable {...}
public class Course implements DataElement {...}


public interface SearchTree<K extends Comparable<Keyable<K>> & Keyable<K>> extends Serializable {...}
public class MySearchTree implements SearchTree<Course> {
...
    private class Node {
        public Course data;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;
        ...
    }
}
```

When trying to use the Course class within the declaration of MySearchTree, I receive a type argument error stating that "Course is not within the bounds of type-variable K". I spent a good amount of time trying to figure out what attributes Course might be lacking to make it not fit the bill, but came up empty.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `MySearchTree` the `K` of the base type is `Course`. So `K` must "extend" `Comparable<Keyable<Course>> & Keyable<Course>`. But it doesn't, it extends `Comparable<Keyable<DataElement>> & Keyable<DataElement>`.

I guess **`DataElement`** should be generified in a similar manner to **`Comparable`** or **`Enum`**.

```
public interface Keyable <T> {public String getKey();}

public interface DataElement<THIS extends DataElement<THIS>> extends Comparable<Keyable<THIS>>, Keyable<THIS>, Serializable {...}
public class Course implements DataElement<Course> {...}


public interface SearchTree<K extends Comparable<Keyable<K>> & Keyable<K>> extends Serializable {...}
public class MySearchTree implements SearchTree<Course> {
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a ton. You just saved me hours worth of headaches.